# Invalid JSON formatting in Volley post request

Tags: java, android, json, post, android-volley

I am trying to pass

```
 data={"process" : "ExampleProcess", "phone" : "123456"}
```

As a post request in volley, thus far I have managed to create a(very basic) method that will send
the required information out to the server, but I am getting a failed response.

I added logs to the program for which I can see

ERROR:: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 2 of

But I believe it has to do with the way I am trying to send my information over. Upon debugging I also came to realize that I was getting an error indicating

Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString();

For which I do not know what to do, even if I change the:

```
        total.put("data", data.toString());
```

to

```
        total.put("data", data);
```

The error will persist. At this point I have no clue as to how can I go about sending the correct JSON post request to my URL(which has been taken out from the example btw)

```
public void volleyConnector(String url) {
        final JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        final JSONObject total = new JSONObject();


        try {

            data.put("process", "ExampleProcess");
            data.put("phone"  , "123456789");
            total.put("data", data.toString());

        } catch(JSONException e) {

            Log.v("JSON ERROR: ", e.toString());
        }


         JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( url, total, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.v("--------------","---------------------------");
                Log.v("RESPONSE: ", "-----> " + response.toString());
                Log.v("<----- BTW------>", total.toString());
                Log.v("--------------","---------------------------");

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.v("--------------","---------------------------");
                Log.v("RESPONSE: " , "xXxX FAIL X_____X FAIL XxXx");
                Log.v("|>>>ERROR:    ", error.toString());
                //Log.v("|>>>ERROR:    ", error.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.v("<----- BTW------>", total.toString());

                Log.v("--------------","---------------------------");


            } // end of onErrorREsponse
        }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return headers;
                }

        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } // end of volley connector method
```

My complete error log(upon the failed request) reads:

```
V/RESPONSE:: xXxX FAIL X_____X FAIL XxXx
V/|>>>ERROR:: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of i 
V/<----- BTW------>: {"data":"{\"process\":\"ExampleProcess\",\"phone\":\"123456789\"}"}
```

I am not too sure as to what is going on and I am not getting anywhere by reading the docs and debugging with Android studio. As far as I am concerned, one of the parameters is a JSONObject and I am passing in one albeit it might be wrongly formatted.

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing correct but try code once by making one small change in your code that is-

```
JSONObject data= new JSONObject();

            data.accumulate("username", "mobileGps");
            data.accumulate("password", "9565551236");

            JSONObject total= new JSONObject();
            total.put("data",data);

            json = jsonObjectNew.toString();
```

And pass this "json" to method and check once. Looking same but try once.

Comment: I tried it but it still would not work for some reason, eventually I ended up choosing to send the JSON information as a StringRequest() and it worked. I have no clue as to why it would not work with regular JsonObjRequests